How many polyominoes have a bounding box that can fit into an $8\times8$ matrix?
I understand the title might not be clear so let me explain. Say you have the set that includes all the fixed polyominoes. This would include a monomino, 2 dominoes, 6 tromino and so on. We usually demote the area of a polyomino as n so the monomino would be n = 1, the domino as n = 2, and so on.
I know all the polyominoes from size n = 1 to n = 8 would fit to the 8x8 matrix because the longest one would be the octomino, whose dimensions are 1 by 8. The sum of them so far is 3,792.
For the nonomino, the 1 by 9 wouldn't fit but the rest should. The 1 by 9 would be the longest and all other should be 8 by x or less. There are 9,910 nomominoes so that - 1 + 3,792 so far.
For decomino, I think it would follow some pattern but I'm not sure. I have a feeling that there would be 2 that wouldn't fit. The 1 by 10 and another where it's 1x9 + a cell under the last cell making the bounding box 2x9.
I have a suspicion that the pattern for the ones that don't fit is the sequence for fixed polyonimoes A001168, but only up to a certain size. It would eventually max out when n = 64, in which there would only be 1 polyomino from that set. It starts at 1, goes to some big number, and then comes back down to 1, which makes me think it's going to be some n choose r function.
I can probably brute force it with Redelmeier's algorithm, but I was wondering if this can be calculated easier.

"The sum of them so far" means what? If the total are is that number, how do they all fit in an $8\times 8$ square?

Do you count reflections as different polyonimos?

The question, how many polyominoes are there for a given values of $n$, doesn't have a simple answer, does it? I wouldn't think the question you raise would be any easier.

I guess to get two dominos, you have to consider rotations different, so it would seem you'd also take reflections different.

Since you neither link to a definition nor provide one, is a polyonimo simply connected, or does the eight square consisting of a $3\times3$ square minus the middle count?

Basically, as written, this question is terribly ill-defined.

Once you clarify the questions above, this might be hard. Generally speaking, questions involving enumerating polyominoes are hard and there is often no known closed form. For specific small $n$ it may be possible to count the number fitting in a $n\times n$ box but even $n=8$ might be tricky unless there are some restrictions on their shape. see for example https://oeis.org/A331968 or https://oeis.org/A126765

@ThomasAndrews I'm talking about each one individually. Consider each polyomino individually and if it's bounding box would fit into an 8x8, then add it the count. This isn't a packing problem.
In regards to reflections and rotations, I said fixed so yes, rotations and reflections are considered unique.
As far as definitions goes, I mean the wikipedia definition: A polyomino is a plane geometric figure formed by joining one or more equal squares edge to edge. It is a polyform whose cells are squares. It may be regarded as a finite subset of the regular square tiling.

@ThomasAndrews And also, yes, and 3 x 3 with a hole in the middle would count. I'm not referring to any subset like convex, row-convex or simply connected. I mean all of them.

@JairTaylor I see. I know a(n) has been calculated up to n = 24. I think brute forcing it might be my only option. Hopefully by keeping it within the bounds of a matrix, I can calculate it before the heat death of the universe.

Some numbers of that kind are in https://vixra.org/abs/1905.0474

The number of fixed polyominoes that will fit in an n by n square is given by the sum of S(i,j) for all pairs of i,j with 1<=i<=n and 1<=j<=n, where S(w,h) is the number of fixed polyominoes of width precisely equal to w and height precisely equal to h. 
The values of S may be found in the OEIS sequence A292357, at link https://oeis.org/A292357 
The values of S are organised in a sequence, as explained on the sequence page.
By summing the relevant values of the sequence, for an 8x8 square you arrive at the figure 50303895480064088.
